# Match Java Map keyset values with String values of a Java list of objects

Tags: java, list, collections, compare, java-stream

I have a Java list of objects which each one contains a String value (code). Also I have a Java Map. I want to check whether all the elements in the Map keys are included in the list of the String values.

The Model class :

```
public class Obj {

private String code;
private String name;
private String uom;

public Obj(String code, String name, String uom) {
    this.code = code;
    this.name = name;
    this.uom = uom;
  }

}
```

the implemention :

```
private static final Obj weight = new Obj("weight", "Weight", "Kg");
private static final Obj height = new Obj("height", "Height", "cm");
public static final List<Obj> objMasters = List.of(weight, height);


Set<String> keySet = map.keySet(); // returns the keyset values from the Map

boolean match =objMasters.stream()
  .anyMatch(objMaster -> objMaster.getCode().matches(keySet.toString()));
```

But with this implementation I always get false as the value for the match. What has gone wrong here?

Comment: You are talking about a “list of the String values” but are showing a `List<Obj>` in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I now understood about your question, try this.

```
List<String> codes = objMasters.stream().map(obj -> obj.getCode()).collect(Collectors.toList());
boolean match = codes.containsAll(keySet);
```

Comment: "doesnt work. it returns true for both even if there is an element which does not include in the objMasters"

Comment: @UdaraSeneviratne This should work now, unless your keyset isn't what you want to check in the list.

Comment: but if the map values are empty, still it returns true

Comment: @UdaraSeneviratne well that is an edge case, if you don't want that then just put an and.  boolean match = codes.containsAll(keySet) && !keySet.isEmpty();

Comment: Further collecting to `Set` would be better to ensure unique elements and checking their existence.

Answer (score 0):

0，when you use collection or map，please override equals and hashCode methods
/n1，you can deep study of source code like get()  contain() and others methods
/n2, by then you will undunderstand why